# remove Highlighted Text SectionWise in Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am following this plugin https://github.com/mir3z/texthighlighter for text Highlighitng in IFrame. Upon Selection Text if i want to remove perticular section of the Selected{colored} text it is not happening. even though this plugin provides removing of highlighted text line by line ... but i need it differently as below

```
     (function() {

                var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeDiv'), colors = new ColorPicker(
                        document.querySelector('.color-picker')), hltr;
                var i = 0;
                highlights = 1;
                iframe.onload = function() {
                    var hltr = new TextHighlighter(
                            iframe.contentDocument.body,
                            {
                                onAfterHighlight : function(range, highlights) {
                                    i++;
                                    var xColor = $('.selected').css(
                                            'border-right-color');
                                    highlights[highlights.length - 1].parentNode.innerHTML += '<div class="clored_div'+i+'" style="position: absolute;right: 13px;width: 40px;border-right: 14px solid '+xColor+';height: 40px;background:none;border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;border-top: 10px solid transparent;box-shadow: none;height: 0;margin: 0 auto 20px;width: 0;"><img id="removeHighLight" onClick="removeColor();"; title="<fmt:message key="colorRemove"/>" src="<fmt:message key="images"/>/close_rm.png" alt="Close" style="height: 15px;position: absolute;right: -21px;top: -23px;width: 15px;z-index: 9999;"/></div><div id=section' + i +'></div>'


                                     function removeColor(){
                                    $('.clored_div"'+i+'"').remove();
                                    } 

                                },


                    colors.onColorChange(function(color) {
                        hltr.setColor(color);
                    });


                };
//for the src HTML please keep any HTML under same application and access like this
                iframe.src = 'http://localhost:8080/html/example.htm';
            })();
```

i want to call this function of this section of colored text in order to remove the color.

```
function removeColor(){$('.clored_div"'+i+'"').remove();}
```

anyOne help me out with this problem.. if you need more code or understanding for this problem please ask
Thank you so much in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

**parent.removeColor();**

Iframe is having this function declared, but it is defined in mainPage.